# Why can't I get an override template to work?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I recently had a task dumped on me, all I need to do is add a link header to a template in joomla.  I'm able to do this directly inside the default.php in

```
/modules/mod_articles_category/tmpl/default.php
```

but of course it shows up in any module that uses that template, which isn't acceptable.

I havn't touched joomla before yesterday and I'm suprised at how painful this has become!

I've been following tutorials, creating an override template in

```
templates/template_name/html/mod_articles_category/default.php
```

but I dont see any option to utilize this override template in the module options of the admin console.

I also tried creating a duplicate of the module itself with the link header simply added into the default.php file but don't have any option to have this module installed since there is no module manager extension, just barebones joomla 3. What I'd like to do is use the override template, since it seems like the simplest solution.

What am i doing wrong that I cant see any effect from my override template?

Comment: Please explain this briefly. I am a bit confused. `but I dont see any option to utilize this override template in the module options of the admin console.

I also tried creating a duplicate of the module itself with the link header simply added into the default.php file but don't have any option to have this module installed since there is no module manager extension, just barebones joomla 3. What I'd like to do is use the override template, since it seems like the simplest solution.`

Comment: If I am in admin console and click extentions --> modules
then navigate to the module that I want to use my override template, i see no option to select the override template and it is not using the override automatically.

I tried creating a custom module, which is basically a clone of mod_articles_category, but with the added changes I wanted.  I do not have any 'module manager' or 'extension manager' that i have seen in other tutorials online, so I seem to have no way of installing my custom module.

It seems like if I am able to make my desired module use my override template

Comment: It seems like if I am able to make my desired module use my override template that would be enough to solve the issue.  I have only begun with joomla in the past 24 hours so forgive me if I approach this incorrectly.

Comment: Do you want to select a custom layout in module's `Alternative Layout` ?

Comment: or do you want to override the default module's output?

Comment: Just trying to add a very simple 

    <h3><a href="https://urlgoeshere.com">Link Title</a></h3>

to one of the modules, I only want to override it for one of the modules where there are two sections of the homepage that use the same module.

essentially trying to make the Title a link by this type of workaround

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file `templates/template_name/html/mod_articles_category/default.php` to something custom like `templates/template_name/html/mod_articles_category/linkInHeader.php` then save it.

Go to your module manager and open that module. GO to `Advanced` tab & select `linkInHeader` in `Alternative Layout` dropdown. This should do the tricks.

Comment: Interesting this is where i hit a wall yesterday.  I have done as you said within the module management.   When I click on the alternative layout dropdown all i see is:
    --from module---
    default

..no options to select anything other than default

Comment: could it be possible that this issue is occuring because i do not have 'module manager' that i see in some tutorials?  In my admin console all i have is 'Extensions'-->'modules'.  It's very confusing since i do see the option for alternate layout.

Comment: I am confused about `'Extensions'-->'modules'.` Which version of joomla are you using? Purge all cache and layout should be there.

Comment: when i login as admin, i dont have anything called 'module manager', just at the top menu bar I am able to click extensions dropdown, then selecting 'modules'.  This is what i meant by 'extensions'---> modules'.  This is joomla 3.6.1.

Comment: In that case... got to `Extensions=>Discover`, you will see several installer plugins listed after discovery. Install them and enable them in the plugin manager. This will bring back your installer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this, I believe the discover extension function is stripped out by the one who deployed the site.  Will have to discuss with them about requirements.